# Convert price Post to correct value insert into MySql

Tags: php, regex

Can't figure out how to get inputs like these correct in a mysql database (DECIMAL 10,2).

Let's say people insert numbers like these in an input field:

```
1024,25
1,024,25
1.024.25
```

or even mistakes and weird ones like:

```
10,24.25
and 10.24,25
or 1,000,000.25
and 1.00,0.000,25
```

And then with PHP, convert all these variations to get inserted in the database as:

```
1024.25 --> for all possible inputs just one **dot** in the number before the cents
```

number_format doesn't work, as well as all the regex' I've tried. I always get stuck on another variation with the numbers.

Feels like I've tried all the examples on internet so far. Any help is welcome.

Comment: i wouldent want to guess what the user wanted, seems dangerous. Instead i would validate, if the validation fails the user would have to input the price again.

Comment: That is a good suggestion but in the EU we work with different numbers than the database wants. I don't want to educate them on things they don't know about.

Answer (score 4):

1. You specify the format you're expecting. If the format isn't met, do NOT accept the value - ask the user to correct it!
2. Define your cases: what is valid, what can be accepted with a little good-will, what is invalid?

US: 1,000,000.25

EU: 1.000.000,25 (most of EU)

P.S.: For the database you'll need the dot as decimal separator.

Edit:
In most cases it is sufficient to declare decimal and thousand separator, then remove the thousand separator from the string entirely (it has no meaning, but is merely a helper for better readability).

Verify that the remaining string has only one decimal separator. If you allow numbers without a decimal separator, then zero would be accepted as well. Not more... also make sure, the rest is only digits.

When this is all given, you can convert the string into a format that the database understands.

Example code (try yourself)

```
$thousandSeparator = '.';
$decimalSeparator = ',';
$incoming = '1005.666.322,56';
$working = str_replace($thousandSeparator, '', $incoming);
$isOk = preg_match('/^[0-9]+'.($decimalSeparator).'{0,1}[0-9]*$/', $working);
$converted = str_replace($decimalSeparator, '.', $working);
$formatted = number_format($converted, 2, $decimalSeparator, $thousandSeparator);
var_dump($isOk, $incoming, $working, $converted, $formatted);
```

Comment: That is mainly where I use number_format for; to convert the real numbers to their locales.

Comment: But number_format doesn't convert the number, it formats it.. that's a difference

Answer (score 0):

I ran into sprintf, and think I figured it out. Never used it before but it does the trick. Let me know what you think.

```
$num = "1.00,0.000,25";
$num = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', "$num");
$num = sprintf('%.2f', $num / 100);
```

result: 1000000.25

```
$num = "1,038,25";
$num = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', "$num");
$num = sprintf('%.2f', $num / 100);
```

result: 1038.25

Comment: This code assumes that there are always 2 decimal places. Any more or less decimal place will produce a wrong result.

Comment: don't try to be smart here, aks the user. First example is a good one, you cannot really know what the user wanted to type - maybe he made a mistake and copy/pasted another number into the field. Trying to "repair" that might be fatal (assume it's money that gets debitted from YOUR bank account - makes i difference if it is 1.00000025 or 10000000.25 don't you think so?)

Comment: You are actually very helpful and giving me great insights. The use here is just a two decimal input for prices. It will do in this case. Thanks for thinking along on this!

Comment: My tipp to make it easier for you: define the decimal and thousand separators. Upon receiving the value (as string), remove all thousand separators (because these are only "human helpers" for better readability) and make sure there is only 1 decimal separator and the rest only digits. When you want to output the number, use number_format() with your settings... There might be cases where the user has to confirm his inputs (like when you make a bank transfer, you enter your values and before it goes over the wire, you see a summary page and must confirm them)

Comment: That was my entire problem in the first place :-).  I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I edited my post with some comments and some example code.. enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks! But the problem here is still: when changing the comma into a dot, I suddenly get a lot richer.

Comment: Why is that? Is the comma your decimal separator?